# Leaflet: how can I move a bounding box to a new center?

Tags: leaflet

How could I move a bounding box to a new center using Leaflet?
There is a [getCenter()](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#bounds-getcenter) method, but not a setCenter() one...

Comment: why downvoted ?

Comment: I suspect this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Assuming that "a bbox can be moved" shows lack of knowledge of projections, which leads me to suspect there is some deeper problem in here. So, what's the use case for moving a bbox around?

Comment: @ IvanSanchez: I want to be able to place an image on a map and dynamically move it.

Comment: Bounding box is property of object(s), not a thing by itself. You can move object(s) and by moving them, bounding box will move. So please edit your question and describe what you want to do  (like in a comment to IvanSanchez).

Comment: Yeah, this is a XY problem indeed. @gordie doesn't want to move a bounding box, but to move an overlaid image instead. I'm gonna guess that a plugin like https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Drag or https://github.com/ScanEx/Leaflet.imageTransform would cover the use case.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it doing like that :

```
  var anchorPos = anchorMarker.getLatLng();
  var bounds = overlay.getBounds();

  anchorMarker.on('drag', function (e) {
    var oldPos = anchorPos;
    var newPos = e.target.getLatLng();

    var offset = [
      newPos.lat - oldPos.lat,
      newPos.lng - oldPos.lng,
    ]

    var northWestPos = new L.LatLng(bounds.getNorth() + offset[0],bounds.getWest() + offset[1]);
    var southEastPos = new L.LatLng(bounds.getSouth() + offset[0],bounds.getEast() + offset[1]);

    //updates
    bounds = L.latLngBounds(northWestPos,southEastPos);
    anchorPos = newPos;

  });
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that the size of the bounding boxes is different (when measured on visible pixels on the screen at any given zoom level, or on projected map units).

Comment: Marker `setLatLng` method would be much simpler and the right method to use if object (image?) size has to stay the same at all zoom lavels.